# Recommendation when using Sys.sleep() in R with rvest

Tags: r, sleep, rvest, sys

I am scraping thousands of webpages using the R package `rvest`. In order not to overload the server, I timed the `Sys.sleep()` function with 5 seconds.

It works nice until we reach a value of ~400 webpages scraped. However, beyond this value, I get nothing and all data is empty, although an error is not thrown.

I am wondering whether there is any possibility to modify the `Sys.sleep()` function to scrape 350 webpages by 5 seconds each, then wait for instance 5 minuts, then continue with another 350 webpages... and so on.

I was checking the `Sys.sleep()` function documentation, and only `time` appears as an argument. So, if this is not possible to be done with this function, is there any other possibility or function to deal with this problem when scraping a huge bunch of pages?

**UPDATE WITH AN EXAMPLE**

This is part of my code. The object `links` is composed of more than 8 thousand links.

```
title <- vector("character", length = length(links))
short_description <- vector("character", length = length(links))

for(i in seq_along(links)){
  Sys.sleep(5)
  aff_link <- read_html(links[i])
  title[i] <- aff_link %>%
    html_nodes("title") %>% 
    html_text()
  short_description[i] <- aff_link %>%
    html_nodes(".clp-lead__headline") %>% 
    html_text()
}
```

Comment: FWIW udemy has an API, restricts scraping in the robots.txt and terms of service. If it's not udemy and not an internal URL, you should share what it is as some SO contributors are not in the habit of helping content thieves. Other SO helpers beware that `clp-lead__headline` CSS class is a highly associated with udemy content pages.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a check on the modulus of a loop variable and do an extra sleep every N iterations. Example:

```
> for(i in 1:100){
  message("Getting page ",i)
  Sys.sleep(5)
  if((i %% 10) == 0){
    message("taking a break")
    Sys.sleep(10)
  }
 }
```

Every 10 iterations the expression `i %% 10` is `TRUE` and you get an extra 10 seconds sleep.

I can think of more complex solutions but this might work for you.

One other possibility is to check if a page returns any data, and if not, sleep twice as long and try again, repeating this a number of times. Here's some semi-pseudocode:

```
get_page = function(page){
   sleep = 5
   for(try in 1:5){
     html = get_content(page)
     if(download_okay(html)){
      return(html)
     }
     sleep = sleep * 2
     Sys.sleep(sleep)
    }
    return("I tried - but I failed!")
}
```

Some web page getters like CURL will do this automatically with the right options - there may be a way to wangle that into your code too.

Comment: thanks for answering. I updated the question with part of my code with the functions in `rvest`. How could I adapt your answer with my code?

Comment: You can use the first technique almost directly since your loop variable is `i` and runs from 1 to the number of pages you are getting. Use the `modulo` operator (`%%`) with the divisor you want (350) and make a big sleep every 350 pages.