# Using sys.sleep in rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape some data from websites with `rvest`. I have a tibble of thousands of URLs, and I need to extract one piece of data from each URL. In order to not be blocked by the main site I'm visiting, I need to rest about 2 minutes after each 200 URLs I visit (learned this via trial and error). I'm wondering how I can use sys.sleep to do this.

My current code is below. I am going to each URL in url_tibble and pulling data (".verified").

```
# Function to extract data
get_data <- function(x) {
  read_html(x) %>%
    html_nodes(".verified") %>%
    html_attr("href") 
}

# Extract data
data_I_need <- url_tibble %>%
  mutate(profile = map(url, ~ get_data(.x)),)
```

This code works for a limited number of URLS, until I get blocked for trying to scrape from the site too quickly. To avoid being blocked, I'd like to pause for 2 minutes after each 200 URLs using sys.sleep. Can you help me figure out how to do this?

The best recommendation I found for how to do this was from the solution posted on [Recommendation when using Sys.sleep() in R with rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790273/recommendation-when-using-sys-sleep-in-r-with-rvest), but I can't figure out how to integrate the solution with my code. This solution uses loops instead of `map`. I tried doing something like this:

```
output <- vector(length = length(url_tibble$url))
                 
for(i in 1:length(url_tibble$url)) {
  data_I_need <-  read_html(url_tibble$url[i]) %>%
          html_nodes(".verified") %>%
          html_attr("href") 
  output[i] <- data_I_need
    if((i %% 200) == 0){
      Sys.sleep(160)
    }
  }
```

However, this does not work either, and I receive an error message.

Comment: Use `seq` and move every 200 indices, then sleep. Probably easier to do this is in `*apply` or `map` like functions. Could you share part of your tibble?

Comment: @NelsonGon here's part of the tibble! structure(list(url = c("https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/New-York/a?page=1", 
"https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/New-York/a?page=2", 
"https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/New-York/a?page=3", 
"https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/New-York/a?page=4", 
"https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/New-York/a?page=5", 
"https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/New-York/a?page=6"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

Comment: * I'm basically just trying to scrape individual therapist URLs from the Psychology Today directory pages (the directory pages are in the tibble above)

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm not quite sure where or how to insert `seq` into my map command, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: Try this: `if(i %in% seq(0, length(url_tibble$url), by = 200)){
    Sys.sleep(160)
  }`. I cannot test as I have no `rvest` installed on my current pc. Might need to use 1 instead of 0 for 1 indices if you prefer.

Comment: what is the point of the pause? Do you want to skip these or simply pause? Currently, the pause is executed after the connection is read which seems counterintuitive.

Comment: @NelsonGon I want to pause after each 200 URLs scraped, because if I scrape more than 200 at a time, the website blocks me. Does that make sense? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `lapply` in lieu of a loop. Also, I have added an `https://` to each URL such that `read_html` recognises them as links not files. We should replace `2` with `200` for the actual data.

```
 lapply(1:length(url_tibble$url), function(x){
  if(x%%2 == 0){
    print(paste0("Sleeping at ", x))
    Sys.sleep(20)
  }
  read_html(paste0("https://",url_tibble$url[x])) %>%
    html_nodes(".verified") %>%
    html_attr("href") 
})
```

Output (truncated)

```
[1] "Sleeping at 2"
[1] "Sleeping at 4"
[1] "Sleeping at 6"
[[1]]
 [1] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/aak-bright-start-rego-park-ny/936718"                   
 [2] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/leslie-aaron-new-york-ny/148793"                        
 [3] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/lindsay-aaron-frieman-new-york-ny/761657"               
 [4] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/fay-m-aaronson-brooklyn-ny/840861"                      
 [5] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/anita-aasen-staten-island-ny/291614"                    
 [6] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/aask-therapeutic-services-fishkill-ny/185423"           
 [7] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/amanda-abady-brooklyn-ny/935849"                        
 [8] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/denise-abatemarco-new-york-ny/143678"                   
 [9] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/raya-abat-robinson-new-york-ny/810730"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works for me! The only part that didn't work was the pasting of the "https://" -- whenever I paste this in, I get "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Could not resolve host: https". If I exclude this bit, though, it works for me!

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked for you.